# ¿Cómo puedo obtener todos los valores de mas una clase de elementos en jQuery y procesarlos?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un problema, ¿como le puedo hacer para leer los valores de dos o mas clases de inputs con jQuery y procesarlos?.

Puedo leer los valores de un elemento de clases pero no se como manejar mas de un elemento de clases al mismo tiempo, ya que estos datos serán dinámicos.

Si en usuario desea introducir mas personas los inputs se irán generando con el nombre de sus respectivas clases, y que posteriormente serán enviadas a una BD cada grupo de valores de clases.

Ejemplo:

> name: 'Juan', apellido: 'Perez'
>   name: 'Juan', apellido: 'Garcia'

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <input type='text' class='nombres' value='Carlos'>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type='text' class='apellidos' value='Perez'>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <input type='text' class='nombres' value='Juan'>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type='text' class='apellidos' value='Garcia'>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <input type='text' class='nombres' value='Ramiro'>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type='text' class='apellidos' value='Vazquez'>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Yo obtengo los valores así

```
$('.nombres').each(function(){
  var nombre=$(this).val();
});
```

Ya después de esto ir metiendo uno por uno a la BD, pero ahí ya no se como obtener el correspondiente apellido a ese nombre y mandarlo juntos a una fila en la BD.

Si alguien me pudiera brindar su ayuda, solo que me diga como recoger esos valores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres usando `parents()` y `find()` asi:

```js
$('.nombres').each(function(){
  var nombre=$(this).val();
  var apellido=$(this).parents('tr').find('.apellidos').val();
  console.log(nombre + ' ' + apellido);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <input type='text' class='nombres' value='Carlos'>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type='text' class='apellidos' value='Perez'>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <input type='text' class='nombres' value='Juan'>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type='text' class='apellidos' value='Garcia'>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <input type='text' class='nombres' value='Ramiro'>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type='text' class='apellidos' value='Vazquez'>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha servido mucho.